# Can not call another REST request in mongoose findOne() NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

I'm newbie in NodeJS. I used Mongoose to check the existing item, if the item is not exist then will call another REST API, but it throw the error when running.

```
//check if hotel is existing
HotelModel.findOne({ name: hotel.name }, { name: 1 }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        return
    }
    if (result) {
        return 
    }

    var address = await getHotelAddress(hotel.id) => throw error
});
```

and here is the error log:

```
var address = await  getHotelAddress(hotel.id)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
```

It seems to can not call another task in `findOne`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where have you defined `getHotelAddress` function ?

Comment: @UsmanRana: I defined `getHotelAddress` function in the same file

Comment: `findOne` is not asynchronous and so you can't use await inside the callback.. More info : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne

Comment: can we see the declaration of the function ?

Comment: did you declare this function to work as async ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanHussien: I declare this function as below:

function getHotelAddress(hotelID) {
    return new Promise.all(async function (resolve, reject) {
        var response = await SupportFunction.makeRequest(url)
        var json = JSON.parse(response)
        var hotel = json.hotel
        var address = hotel.address
    
        resolve(address)
    })
}